# How to fetch AD distinguished names (DN) in a bulk way

Tags: python, active-directory

I am fetching AD distinguished name (DN) by the python code below

```
...
enter code herequery = '(sAMAccountName=%s)' % utils.conv.escape_filter_chars(name)
resp = self.search(query, ad_server=ad_server)
...
```

It fetches a DN for one single AD user.

How can I fetch DN for multiple AD user names, in a bulk way?
So, I am passing a list of ad usernames and getting list of DN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can arrange an OR-type LDAP query, e.g.:

```
query = '(|%s)' % ''.join(['(sAMAccountName=%s)' % utils.conv.escape_filter_chars(x) for x in names])
```

That would produce a query like `(|(sAMAccountName=foo)(sAMAccountName=bar))` that would be interpreted by LDAP server.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer!  will try that out)